# How to join 2 tables which cardinality is many-to-many

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many

I need to build table, which contain info about customer and cars which he bought by type of buy.
So we have

- Customers(customer_id,name,passport...)
- Buys(buy_id,customer_id,car_id,...,buy_type)
- Cars(car_id,car_brand,car_model.....)

How i can build table like this (customer_name,car_brand,car_model) by buy type.

Comment: What you're looking for is an [**associative entity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), also known as a **bridging table**. Your `buys` table needs to associate IDs of customers to IDs of cars.

Comment: @Obsidian Age i have table buys which links customer and cars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is to use two different JOINs as follows:

```
SELECT CU.customer_name, CA.car_brand, CA.car_model
FROM Customers CU
JOIN Buys B
  ON CU.customer_id = B.customer_id
JOIN Cars CA
  ON CA.car_id = B.car_id
ORDER BY B.buy_type DESC
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I stuck at this query in my course work.

Comment: Glad to hear this solution appears to have worked for you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)